# How to run a command every time that I exit a zsh shell (including non-login shells)

Tags: zsh, configuration, logout

I have been trying to run a command to clean up some of my temporary files every time I exit a shell.

I initially thought that this would be the job of `.zlogout` but it doesn't seem to be executed if I, for example, have multiple shells open in my terminal emulator (kitty).
From what I have found in the doc, `.zlogin` and `.zlogout` apply to login shells only, which, correct me if I am wrong, is not the case when you simply open different tabs or windows in your terminal emulator.

What is the equivalent of `.zlogout` for non-login shells and alternatively what would be the recommended way to achieve a similar effect in non-login shells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an example in this [zsh guide](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Guide/zshguide02.html#l9) which sources `~/.zlogout` for non-login shells
using the [`TRAPEXIT`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Trap-Functions) function. This seems to be exactly what you want.

```
TRAPEXIT() {
    # commands to run here, e.g. if you 
    # always want to run .zlogout:
    if [[ ! -o login ]]; then
      # don't do this in a login shell
      # because it happens anyway
      . ~/.zlogout
    fi
  }
```

Add this function to your `~/.zshrc`.

Answer (score 4):

Add a function like

```bsh
function shellExit {
  # Your commands
}
```

along with a trap such as

```bsh
trap shellExit EXIT
```

in `.zshrc`